# Can anyone show me, how to solve these system of Equations:

Tags: polynomials, diophantine-equations

$$\begin{align*}
x+y+z &= 2 \\
(x+y)(y+z)+(y+z)(z+x)+(z+x)(x+y) &= 1 \\
x^2(y+z)+y^2(z+x)+z^2(x+y) &= -6
\end{align*}$$

Can anyone explain me the solution. I asked it in mathoverflow but god knows why it was closed. Please help and detail the process in step by step. It is a RMO question (The Pre- Indian team selection exam for IMO)

Comment: MathOverflow is for questions of interest to research-level mathematicians. Did you read their FAQ [as was suggested to you](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/131519/solution-of-equation-closed)?

Comment: Hi, welcome Math.SE. Have you tried the problem? If so, could you show us the work you've done so far, and we can try to help you from there. Thanks.

Comment: And where are these equations coming from? A homework assignment, something you're thinking about on your own (if so, what is it?), etc.

Comment: Are you supposed to solve for all of $x,y,z,X,Y,Z$ or just $x,y,z$???

Comment: To clarify for any confused users: the RMO is a sit-down exam used for the Indian IMO team selection process. This is probably a past question from one of the exams.

Comment: it was my mistake, there are only 3 variables

Comment: @AlexBecker: Actually, RMO is a selection exam to an exam where the actual selection will be held. Just like British Math Olympiad $1st$ round.

Comment: @Inceptio Thanks for the correction. The relevant point is that (according to the resources I found) the exam is sit-down, so unless Henry is an *unusually* ambitious cheater this can't possibly be an ongoing contest problem.

Comment: What do you mean by ambitious cheater. It is a past problem and neither is my name Henry the Conqueror or Henry. Will anyone give me the answer and the process of solution.

Comment: @HenrytheConqueror: Chill down. Do *not* be rude, if you want to get answers. Can you tell me which year's question is this?

Comment: Well I am not rude but it is rude to claim someone is an "ambitious cheater" !! It is of RMO 2008

Comment: Are you pretty sure? I have the series of all questions and solutions since $2001$. I didn't find the question in *RMO-2008*.

Comment: My source is the book "An Excursion in Mathematics" which have list of all RMO problems since 1990.

Comment: You need a condition there. $x,y,z \in \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: It is not mentioned there. Does it mean x,y have to be rational

Comment: No. Normally, they expect to get solutions in integers.

Comment: You earlier wrote Q which denotes rational if I am not terribly wrong

Comment: Yes, my bad. Can you edit some posts to make $20$ reputations, so that we can continue the discussion in chat?

Comment: I do not know what you are meaning, I am new here

Comment: Can you ask one more question, so that I can up-vote and we can discuss in chat?

Comment: Lllllklllllllk I guess it works

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8894/discussion-between-henry-the-conqueror-and-inceptio)

Comment: The chat is not working, I can see your message but cannot respond

Answer (score 1):

So I'll assume you're only looking for integer solutions. Call the equations (1), (2), and (3) respectively. Expand (2):

$ x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + 3x y + 3 x z + 3 y z = 1.$

From this equation, subtract the square of (1) to obtain

$ x y + x z + y z = -3.$

Subtract double this expression from the square of (1) to obtain

$ x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 10.$

Aha! Since $x,y,z$ are integers, this means $x=\pm 3, y=\pm 1, z =0$ or some permutation thereof. (Just look at the various cases. There aren't that many.) By (1), this means $x=3,y=-1,z=0$ or some permutation thereof.

Comment: I made the mistake by not trying to expand the 2nd equation. OK thanks Will Nelson and @Inceptio

Answer (score 0):

$$x+y+z=2$$

$$x^2+y^2+z^2+2(xy+zx+yz)=4$$

The second equation is $x^2+y^2+z^2+3(xy+zx+zy)=1 \implies zx+yz+yx=-3$

You get $x^2+y^2+z^2=10$

Using the $x+y+z=2$ in the third equation.

$x^2(2-x)+y^2(2-y)+z^2(2-z)=-6 \implies 2(x^2+y^2+z^2)-x^3+z^3+z^3=-6$

A little re-arranging would give

$26 =x^3+y^3+z^3 $

$a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc=(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca)$

$26-3xyz=(2)(10-(-3)) \implies 26-26=3xyz \implies $ one of the $x,y,z$ is zero.

Consider $z=0$ (Generality is not lost) Now you have $x^2+y^2=10$ and $yx=-3$

You get solutions as $(x,y,z)=(3,-1,0),(0,-1,3)(0,3,-1),(-1,0,3),(3,0,-1)$ and $(-1,0,3)$.

Answer (score 0):

Generally proceed as:

1. Is calculated $s=x+y+z, q=xy+yz+zx, p=xyz;$
2. Solve the equation $t^3-st^2+qt-p=0.$

Comment: Wow your technique was not known to me. It is nice!!!